# One script for app in Unity game engine (performance difference)

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, unity-game-engine

Is there a difference in performance between the application (in Unity game engine) uses one script (one class) or more scripts (more classes)?

P. S. In case of using multiple scripts only one MonoBehaviour (remaining connected to it classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the performance does not depends on how many scripts you used but it depends on the content of your script.

For example, if you have many `GameObject` that will be instantiated and destroyed rapidly, you should use object pool pattern instead of instantiating and destroying because instantiating and destroying are performance heavy actions.

Another example is about the complexity. An algorithm that performs [image: O(n)] compare to an algorithm that performs [image: O(n2)] can yield a different especially those being executed every frames.